# Javascript - Removing elements in an array that do not begin with a character

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have an array for a piece of homework in JavaScript, that for simplification purposes, I will illustrate with a similar array below.

```js
["Fruit","Vegetables","B Pies","M Pies","Quorn"]
```

There is one element in the array in question that begins with the letter V.
I am required to extract this element, and ONLY this element into a string, without using for loops (perhaps map()?)
How would I scan the array, and only remove the element beginning with V?

Comment: [array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: "How would I scan the array, and only remove the element beginning with V?" you need to remove the elements beginning with V or find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
const arr = ['Fruit','Vegetables','B Pies','M Pies','Quorn'];
let res = arr.find(x => x[0] === 'V');
console.log(res);
```

If there may be multiple elements beginning with that letter, you can use `Array#filter` to get an array of results.

```js
const arr = ['Fruit','Vegetables','B Pies','M Pies','Quorn', 'V2'];
let res = arr.filter(x => x[0] === 'V');
console.log(res);
```